# How to show how many hits has got one page

Tags: 7, flags, nodes

I'm trying to get something like this "viewed: 123 times." on every single node a part from the static pages like about us or contact etc..

Is there a module for it or is better to create a flag for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the Statistics module. Its already there in drupal, just need to enable it

Comment: Just keep in mind that this module can be a serious drag on performance.

Comment: Ashu, you answer is good but as MPD says, it could be a problem for performance and unfortunately i am in a bad shared hosting... That's why I'm considering to use flag.